# c++ stack stringstream function returns integer vs ASCII

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, stack, stringstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

stack<int>aStack;
stack<int>operand1;
stack<int>operand2;
stringstream postfix;

stringstream &postfixExp(string ch)
{
  for(int i =0; i< ch.length(); i++)
  {
      if(ch[i] == '1' || ch[i] == '2' || ch[i] == '3' || ch[i] == '4' || ch[i] == '5' || ch[i] == '6' || ch[i] == '7' || ch[i] == '8' || ch[i] == '9' || ch[i] == '0' )
      {
          aStack.push(ch[i]);
      }

      else if(ch[i] == '+')
      {
        operand1.push(aStack.top());
        aStack.pop();

        operand2.push(aStack.top());
        aStack.pop();

        int x = operand1.top() - 48;
        int y = operand2.top() - 48;
        int result = x + y;

        aStack.push(result);
      }

      else if(ch[i] == '*')
      {
        operand1.push(aStack.top());
        aStack.pop();

        operand2.push(aStack.top());
        aStack.pop();

        int x = operand1.top() - 48;
        int y = operand2.top() - 48;
        int result = x * y;

        aStack.push(result);
      }
  }


  postfix << aStack.top();
  return postfix;

}


int main()
{
  string postfix = "32+2*";

  stringstream * result = &postfixExp(postfix);
  cout << result-> str() ;

  return 0;
}
```

Hi, does anyone know what is wrong with my code above ?
My program should return the value of a postfix notation. I entered "32+2*" as the postfix notation, and it should return 10. Apparently something is going wrong, and it returns -86 instead

I suppose the error comes from this particular code

```
else if(ch[i] == '*')
      {
        operand1.push(aStack.top());
        aStack.pop();

        operand2.push(aStack.top());
        aStack.pop();

        int x = operand1.top() - 48;
        int y = operand2.top() - 48;
        int result = x * y;

        aStack.push(result);
      }
```

from there, I displayed the operand2 and it shows -43 instead of 7 (derives from the previous addition "34+")

Please let me know which part is wrong, why does my operand2 doesnt have a value of 7.

Thank you

Comment: Is your stack supposed to contain ASCII character values or integer numerical values? Some of your code assumes ASCII (`aStack.push(ch[i]);`), some assumes numerical (`aStack.push(result);`). So of course you get nonsensical answers.

Comment: It supposed to be numerical. However someone suggested me to subtract my ASCII with 48. By subtracting those, it will give the correct numerical value from 0-9

Comment: You misunderstood their suggestion. They meant when you push ASCII values onto the stack, not when you remove numerical values from the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  if(ch[i] == '1' || ch[i] == '2' || ch[i] == '3' || ch[i] == '4' || ch[i] == '5' || ch[i] == '6' || ch[i] == '7' || ch[i] == '8' || ch[i] == '9' || ch[i] == '0' )
  {
      aStack.push(ch[i]);
  }
```

This should be:

```
  if(ch[i] == '1' || ch[i] == '2' || ch[i] == '3' || ch[i] == '4' || ch[i] == '5' || ch[i] == '6' || ch[i] == '7' || ch[i] == '8' || ch[i] == '9' || ch[i] == '0' )
  {
      aStack.push(ch[i] - '0');
  }
```

Get rid of the other `- 48`'s as they're broken.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your characters to ints before you push them to the stack. Seems to me your compiler should have warned you about that. Try turning up your warning level.

```
aStack.push(ch[i]);
```

becomes

```
aStack.push(ch[i] - '0'); // '0' is 48
```

Note also that you can use `isdigit` from `<cctype>` rather than comparing `ch[i]` to each digit manually.

Comment: I created local variable int x, int y, and int result to copy and contain the integer value temporarily before I pushed it into the stack. wouldn't it solve the problem ?

Comment: @dodgerblue But your stack contains character values (that's why you need the `- 48`'s). There is no character value for 10. So how can you push the result onto the stack?

Comment: Seems I was wrong about expecting a warning. At least GCC does not warn. I guess a char fits in an int, so it does not warn.

Comment: @David Schwartz Ahh ! You're right, I've never thought about that. So, do you have any suggestion to convert from character to integer properly ?

I'm thinking to use atoi, not sure how to use it though

Comment: You can use `atoi` or you can use `- 48` or `- '0'`. But do it in the right place, when you need to convert ASCII to numerical, not when you read numerical values off the stack.

Comment: @Adam Burry Thanks for the explanation '0' = 48 in ASCII. I got confused for a momment why did subtracting ch[i] with '0' magically solved my problem. I understand it now

Comment: @dodgerblue Short version: `'0' - '0' = 0` `'1' - '0' = 1` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following

```
  else if(ch[i] == '+')
  {
    operand1.push(aStack.top());
    aStack.pop();

    operand2.push(aStack.top());
    aStack.pop();

    int x = operand1.top() - 48;
    int y = operand2.top() - 48;
    int result = x + y;

    aStack.push(result + 48);
   }
```

This will make it 10. You need to change the second aStack.push(result) too.

Comment: This will give him *three* bugs that cancel out.

Comment: well, `char` to int is implicit. I would count that as a bug. Just C style.